# git local branch named -D is created, how to delete it

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

When I tried to remove branch with the command : `git branch –D origin/image`

I this message:

> Branch '–D' set up to track remote branch 'image' from 'origin'.

and now a branch named `"-D"` is created locally buy does not exist globally. How can I remove it as it is a flag of git command and so not letting me delete with this command : `git branch -D -D`.

*using bitbucket and vscode.

Answer (score 6):

##### Use `--` to say `-D` is not meant as an option:

You can use the `--` option to say the rest of the command line is not options, like most Unix/Linux (or Linux originating) commands allow:

```
git branch -d -- -D
```

##### But is it dash-D or hyphen-D?

If that didn't work, check if it's really a hyphen, or if it's one of the several Unicode dashes instead. You used both in the question interchangeably, which is why I ask.

I expect that this is the command you actually need to run, deleting the branch called dash-D (rather than hyphen-D):

```
git branch -d –D
```

Here I cut and pasted that `–D` from the message you got when you created the branch, and although it's subtle, I can confirm it's not a hyphen, it's [U+2013 (en dash)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). You can cut and paste it from the output of `git branch` to make sure you get the exact same dash that's in the branch name.

And of course that would work with the `--` too:

```
git branch -d -- –D
```

Answer (score 3):

You <strike>have to</strike> can use a low-level command:

```
git update-ref -d refs/heads/-D
```